# how to change the size and position of a rechart's pie chart using tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, recharts

I am building react nextJs application with tailwind-css and i am using **Pie-charts** of `recharts`. my charts used to work fine but i am not getting, **how to increase the width and height of a chart?**

```
// <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
<PieChart width={400} height={400}>
  <Pie
    data={payments.payments}
    cx="50%"
    cy="50%"
    labelLine={true}
    label={renderCustomizedLabel}
    outerRadius={80}
    fill="#8884d8"
    dataKey="value"
  >
    {payments.payments.map((entry, index) => (
      <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
    ))}
  </Pie>
  <Tooltip />
</PieChart>
// </ResponsiveContainer>
```

[image: size?]

and if i use tailwind grid system it do not apply changes. **Also how position it on the screen using screen sizes in tailwind?**

Comment: You can done by "outerRadius" property  <Pie
    outerRadius={100}
  >

Answer (score 2):

you can change outerRadius property to increase the piechart size

Comment: Your answer is same as the comment by @Kavitha K T. You may provide some sample code for more detail would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this.

```
<div className="w-64 h-48 use tailwind classes here">
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
        <PieChart>
          <Pie
            data={payments.payments}
            cx="50%"
            cy="50%"
            labelLine={true}
            label={renderCustomizedLabel}
            outerRadius={80}
            fill="#8884d8"
            dataKey="value"
          >
            {payments.payments.map((entry, index) => (
              <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
            ))}
          </Pie>
          <Tooltip />
        </PieChart>
       </ResponsiveContainer>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting outerRadius property to bigger. i.e. outerRadius={200}